# form_tag remote true not processing as json request rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-ujs

I have a form in my application as this

```
<%= form_tag(studios_path, method: :get, id: "studios_filter", remote: true) do %>

<% end %>
```

in my application.js, i have this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require turbolinks
//= require cocoon
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Both somehow whenever this form is submitted, i get it as this

```
Started GET "/studios?utf8=%E2%9C%93&workout_category_id_list=&neighbourhood_list=Kuala+Lumpur&studio_id_list=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-28 12:42:12 +0800
Processing by StudiosController#index as HTML
```

It is processing as HTML instead of processing as JSON since `remote: true` is already added.

Any ideas as to why this happening. Running out of options

Comment: Provided the method isn't incompatible, `remote: true` will set the format of the request to JS and not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description mentioned in the post it seems like you are concerned with the expected request type("json") not being sent over the controller.

So, for it work as mentioned in the post, change the code as below:

```
<%= form_tag(studios_path, method: :get, id: "studios_filter", remote: true, :html => {:'data-type' => 'json'}) do %>
```

This will be processing the request as json type.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `method: :get` in your form, all the form values get appended to the studios_path, you must use this method as`post` and change the method in routes to post. After that you will start getting all the form fields in your controller as a hash

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue: Rails 5 was processing my `remote: true` form submits as `HTML` no matter what I did. The solution for me was to add

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to `application.js`. OP already has this in their file above, which is what made me give it a try. Not sure why OP is still having issues, but this solved it for me ... so maybe this'll solve it for others!